# Receiving a MultiPart file and JSON data using Spring and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring

Here's my controller below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam("data") String campaignJson,
            Principal principal) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
```

I want to be able to receive a `MultipartFile` as well as a JSON string containing data associated to the file (title, description, etc).

I can get `MultipartFile` uploading to work on it's own, and I can receive a JSON string and parse it on its own, but when I have them together in 1 controller, it fails. Whenever I print out the `String campaignJson` it says `[object Object]` instead of the data that I'm sending (when I print out the data being sent in angular, it's in correct JSON format.)

I've tried `@RequestBody`, `@RequestParam`, `@RequestPart`, but to no avail.

**My question is: How do I receive both a MultipartFile and data in the form of JSON in one Spring controller?**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/upload", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public DocumentResource uploadPut(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
        MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

        String next = request.getFileNames().next();
        MultipartFile file = request.getFile(next);
        ..... 
}
```

**Edit :**
Using the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` should not limit you in any way to use other `@PathVariables` or `@RequestParams`, so passing title and description should be possible.

I used it to upload multiple images with AngularJS and `FileUploader`

( [angular-file-upload v1.1.5](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)   )

like this

```
 var uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: config.apiUrl('/machine/' + $scope.id + '/images/'),
        method: "post",
        queueLimit: maxFiles
    });
```

Comment: `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` works for uploading on its own. Does your approach work for uploading media as well as media form data? For instance, if I upload a video as a `MultipartFile` and I want the video to have a title and a description, does parsing the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` allow me to obtain the video AND the title/description as well as any other fields a user inputs?